# Convert list to dictionary in element Or replace special characters in element in data frame of pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I'm working on a dataframe like this in pandas:

```
item_type  item_price  item_env                                        item_detail
sofa          2880     [natural wood, eco-friendly]                 [2pax,seglora]     
sofa          2400     [solid wood, recycle, reuse]                 [3pax,knisa]
chair         1200      nan                                               [Red]
desk          2000      nan                                              [blue]
```

And I want to change to result like this:

```
item_type  item_price  item_env                                        item_detail
sofa          2880     {natural wood, eco-friendly}                 {2pax,seglora}  
sofa          2400     {solid wood, recycle, reuse}                 {3pax,knisa}
chair         1200      nan                                               {Red}
desk          2000      nan                                              {blue}
```

I try to use `replace` and `str.replace` and some other method but it fail. So, I wanna ask how can do to get the expected result?

Comment: what is the output of `print(df.loc[0,'item_env'])` and `print(df.loc[0,'item_detail'])`?

Comment: In the title you are mentioning dicts, but you are currently showing sets in the desired output (e.g. `{natural wood, eco-friendly}`). What do you need?

Comment: Actually this dataframe is converted from a json file and by print(df). In the first dataframe , the element is ``` [natural wood, eco-friendly] ``` and I want to change to ``` {natural wood, eco-friendly} ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the meta character of regular expressions, passing `regex` as `True`, whether you are using `DataFrame.replace` or `Series.str.replace`.

```py
>>> df[['item_env', 'item_detail']] = (df[['item_env', 'item_detail']]
                                        .replace('\[', '{', regex=True)
                                        .replace('\]', '}', regex=True)
                                       )
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
  item_type  item_price                      item_env     item_detail
0      sofa        2880  {natural wood, eco-friendly}  {2pax,seglora}
1      sofa        2400  {solid wood, recycle, reuse}    {3pax,knisa}
2     chair        1200                           NaN           {Red}
3      desk        2000                           NaN          {blue}
```